# Incompatible intel bluetooth and wireless when upgrading Windows 8 to Professional

Tags: windows-8, bluetooth-3.0

I have a ASUS N56VM FHD Notebook Intel Core i7 3610QM with Windows 8.

I want to upgrade to windows 8 Pro (64 bit), but every time I get an error message that Intel Bluetooth and wireless is not compatible and should be removed/deleted.

I updated both drivers, but still get the same message.

Answer (score 0):

I think there will be no problem using them with the PRO version of windows, the two windows versions uses the same drivers!
The Windows Upgrade Advisor always gave me strange messages, especially on "unknown" applications.

Comment: Just press Uninstall and click next.. http://cdn3.pcadvisor.co.uk/cmsdata/features/3357696/Step_3.png